# Attribute Conversion with Hibernate Spatial and PostGIS

Tags: spring-boot, postgis, hibernate-spatial, postgresql-12

In my PostgreSQL 12.2 + PostGIS 2.5.4, I have a table named Address with a column of type `geography(POINT, 4326)`.

I'm working with Hibernate Spatial and trying to develop an Attribute Converter to create the expected Point object from my SpatialLocation object.

The SpatialLocation has basically the coordinates info:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class SpatialLocation {

    private Double latitude;

    private Double longitude;
}
```

Here's the PointFactory component I made:

```
public class PointFactory extends GeometryFactory {

    public Point createPointFromSpatialLocation(SpatialLocation spatialLocation) {

        final Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(spatialLocation.getLatitude(), spatialLocation.getLongitude());

        return createPoint(coordinate);
    }

}
```

Here's the PointConverter:

```
@Component
public class PointConverter implements AttributeConverter<SpatialLocation, Point> {

    @Autowired
    private PointFactory pointFactory;

    @Override
    public Point convertToDatabaseColumn(SpatialLocation spatialLocation) {
        return pointFactory.createPointFromSpatialLocation(spatialLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public SpatialLocation convertToEntityAttribute(Point point) {
        return new SpatialLocation()
                .setLatitude(point.getCoordinate().x)
                .setLongitude(point.getCoordinate().y);
    }

}
```

Here's how the attribute is set on the Address Class:

```
    @Convert(converter = PointConverter.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geography(POINT, 4326)")
    private SpatialLocation spatialLocation;
```

On the service, the Address is created and saved like that:

```
    @Transactional
    public Address saveAddress(final AddressRequest addressRequest) {

        final City city = findOrCreateNewCityService.findOrCreateNewCity(addressRequest.getCityRequest());

        final Address addressToPersist = modelMapper.map(addressRequest, Address.class)
                .setSpatialLocation(modelMapper.map(addressRequest.getSpatialLocationRequest(), SpatialLocation.class))
                .setCity(city);

        log.info("Creating a new Address: '{}'", addressToPersist);
        return addressRepository.save(addressToPersist);
    }
```

When trying to create a new Address, the following error cames up:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unknown unwrap conversion requested: com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry to [B
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.unknownUnwrap(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryJavaTypeDescriptor.unwrap(JTSGeometryJavaTypeDescriptor.java:70) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.3.16.Final.jar:5.3.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryJavaTypeDescriptor.unwrap(JTSGeometryJavaTypeDescriptor.java:26) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.3.16.Final.jar:5.3.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2929) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3760) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

When I directly create the Point object without using the Converter, it works as expected.

Here's some other relevant project details:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect
```

Comment: are you able to solve this ? am facing the same issue using converter. end column binding result is VARBINARY instead of OTHER.

Answer (score 0):

your solution not good for the GIS solution. I think your problem is, the geometry you are trying to insert to table

> com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry

It's type is wrong for postgis, so you must create;

> org.postgis.Point

and your geometry must be;

> org.postgis.PGgeometry

to write postgis column.

If i were you, i use geotools library to import features to postgis. It has a postgis datastore for that. Here is the link:

[Geotools Postgis Datastore](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html)

and there are a lot of examples, how to add, edit, deletes features from datastores.

```
Properties params = new Properties();
params.put("user", "postgres");
params.put("passwd", "postgres");
params.put("port", "5432");
params.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
params.put("database", "test");
params.put("dbtype", "postgis");

DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("tablename");
if (source instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
  SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) source;
  store.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features));
} else {
  System.err.println("Unable to write to database");
}
```

The example code must be like that, i found it on stackoverflow but i didn't tested.